# Word TOC does not display headers within table

Tags: microsoft-word, headers

I've a Table of Content in my Word document. It dislpays correctly all the document headers.

I have a regular table, which some of the cells are defined as a header style. These headers are not displayed on the TOC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would/should the headings of a table show up an element on the TOC?

Comment: Not the heading. The content of table is formatted as a heading.

Comment: Yes but why should the content show up in the TOC of your document? If it's a caption or similar for the table don't make it part of the table but rather use the appropriate tools within Word to create the caption. This might mean you will have to include a table of figures depending on what you're looking at.

Comment: Since the table is a very long one, I would like the users could navigate from the TOC to the specific wanted location within the table.

Comment: Break up your table into individual sections that make them easier to consume. Give each table a dedicated caption and it will show up in the TOC. Aside from that, how did you get the table into the document and how did parts of it receive the heading format? Did you actively select the heading format within Word or did you just select bold and increase the font size?

Comment: You say "some of the cells are defined as a header style". I'm not sure what you mean by that, but if you apply a Header Style to the *text in the cell*, it should appear in the ToC

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, That's exactly what I've done, but the headind does not apear in TOC. Any ideas?